# Cordova Windows Signing and Identities

Tags: windows, cordova, signing

I'm at the verge of releasing our first Windows Phone App, build with Cordova. 
As my Android an iOS binaries are successfully in the stores, I have problems getting things done for windows.

It seems like the generated files have identifiers generated which are not expected by the Windows Store. e.g. I named the id in my config.xml eu.mycompany.clientname after a long wrestle I've generated certificates with my companies information and a strong password etc. as stated in these docs:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/win8/index.html#signing-an-app

After successfully signing I'm uploading my appxupload files to the windows store but I get some (for me) unexpected errors:

```
CordovaApp.Phone_1.0.0.0_anycpu.appxupload1.6 MB
Invalid package identity name: eu.mycompany.clientname (expected: A2DCC7BA.AppName)
Invalid package family name: eu.mycompany.clientname_bzbj8h50hftv4 (expected: A2DCC7BA.AppName_jjthqwjdpvsz2)
Invalid package publisher name: CN=$username$ (expected: CN=E4FE5B9A-B134-4675-9C70-052F6C4B8C82)
```

Not sure why the $username$ is there, it is set correclty in the .Windows_1.0xxx package.

The package identifier I can fix by changing id to the given expecation, that however leaves me unaware of why, and will conflict with my Android Build. The family package is something I'd have to change in the generated platform/windows directory. I don't know why this is required and it will be a pain to do this every time when generating the code (It goes into git without the pplatform directories).

Anyone who can shine some bright lights and maybe even point out a proper guide on these things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this later when I found the app package name and creds in windows store. So setting those in config.xml worked. Also there is no package name override for wp apps, so I set that as default, and overriden it for iOS and Android